# Typescript: create a custom type using a variable's value

Tags: typescript, types

I'm new to TS and I would like to create a custom type

I want to have a custom type (Numbers_2) that accepts some numbers plus the value stored in some variable (n1) and have it work the same way Numbers_1 would

```ts
let n1 = 40;
type Numbers_1 = 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
type Numbers_2 = 10 | 20 | 30 | n1; // 'n1' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof n1'?
let n2: Numbers_2 = 1230; // This line should signal a problem
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Conceptually, types are a "layer above" variables: so types cannot use variables, but variables can use types - if that makes any sense (though TS's [`typeof` _type-operator_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) allows you to work-around this, in a way)

Comment: Just to be clear, the `n1` inside `Number_2` is meant to represent the literal `40` used to initialize `n1`, right? Is there a reason `n1` is `let` instead of `const`?

Comment: ^ Agree... either [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJMbN) is what you're looking for, or what you want is probably impossible.

Comment: You provided what I was looking for, I just didn't try using const ... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can*, by using [TypeScript's `typeof` **type-operator**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) (which is not the same thing as JavaScript's `typeof` operator), but you then also need to change `let n1` to `const n1` because when `n1` is mutable the `typeof n1` is `number` instead of the literal value.

[Like so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBBAjHAvHALABgNzBgTwAcBTOAOQFcBbAI2ICcoB9ZNRTOAHzgCYPuAzPww48RUpVoNmPVHHZdewoYoIkwAMwSJscAPR64AciRG49YhulwYYOAEM4AN3sAbCsQA0cGhXgBLKB9ifwgAczgKKGIAEwcgxzVSAAsGYgA6OAARfzj8MAo4KmJ7CGMkzW0jAH5gV2J4CB4ALnJqOkYmWTYeIV0DOAAVZMC4V1DSKGSC1ziofzCINwc4QnowGnqqYCA):

```js
const n1 = 40;
type Numbers_1 = 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
type Numbers_2 = 10 | 20 | 30 | typeof n1;
let n2: Numbers_2 = 1230;
```

...which results in an error on line 4, which is what your post expects:

> Type '1230' is not assignable to type '`Numbers_2`'.

---

If you want or need `n1` to be mutable, then what you're asking is impossible, by way of demonstration:

```js
let n1 = parseInt( prompt( "What is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything?" ), 10 );

type Numbers_1 = 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
type Numbers_2 = 10 | 20 | 30 | typeof n1; // `n1: number`

let n2: Numbers_2 = 1230; // OK
```

`typeof n1` **has** to be `number` because `parseInt` returns `number` - which in-turn means that `type Numbers_2` is `10 | 20 | 30 | number` which means that `let n2: Numbers_2 = 1230;` is valid and okay.

If you need a `number`-typed "input" variable but still want `Numbers_2` to be constrained to a small set of known, possible values then [you'll need to explicitly *narrow* it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), like so:

```js
type TheAnswer = 42;
type Numbers_2 = 10 | 20 | 30 | TheAnswer;

function isNumbers2( x: number ): x is Numbers_2 {
    switch( number ) {
    case 10:
    case 20:
    case 30:
    case 42:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

//

// `n1` has type `number`
let n1 = parseInt( prompt( "What is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything?" ), 10 );

if( isNumbers2( n1 ) ) {
    // Only within the scope of this `if` statement, `n1` has type `Numbers_2`
}
```